# Iterate through input file in Jupyter Notebook (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a variable called input that is defined like this:

```
input = pd.read_csv('january_2017.csv')
```

then in the middle there is a lot of code

```
...
...
...
...
```

at the end i have a DataFrame called 'df' and i want it to export it as csv as in the line below:

```
df.to_csv('df_january_2017.csv')
```

The problem is that i have 32 files for 32 months. January_2017...December_2017, January_2018....December_2018,...January_2019...December_2019.
And i need to run the code for each of this files, is there a way that i can iterate through this files and it runs the code at the same time for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `import os` and use `os.listdir()` to get a list of all files in a directory.

```
import os

directory = "/directory"

for filename in in os.listdir(directory):
    input = pd.read_csv(filename)
    .
    .
    .
    df.to_csv("df_"+filename)
```

see https://www.newbedev.com/python/howto/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory/ for more.